# Rotating carousel with corresponding caption displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, owl-carousel

There are many jQuery carousels such Bootstrap Carousel or the popular Owl Carousel 2 https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/index.html.

Owl Carousel is great in that it's responsive, touch capable and countless options. You can have images or html in the boxes.

My challenge is I want to have say 3 images and they are always present but the active class rotates between them so for a couple seconds the first would be highlight and the other 2 would be faded out, then the second would be highlighted, and the first and third would be faded out, etc. That is all easy to do with Carousel. The challenge is need a full width box beneath the row of images and that content should correspond to the image that is currently being highlighted like in this graphic:

[image: Rotating captions]

Ideally, I'd like to use Owl since that way if I hover over an image it will pause the rotation and highlight the one im hover over and then resume when I move mouse off, etc. But open to other jquery components that would work better. I'm sure countless solutions exist but not sure what to call this feature since searching for jquery carousels with captions, etc bring up different things that what I'm looking for. Any advice would be most helpful. Also I have bootstrap 3 loaded and can leverage that carousel but think that would be even harder to get what I want out of the box.

Comment: My opinion is you can't do something like this with`Owl` and even if can, hard to change it to this. You can do this easily with native `jquery`.

Comment: Open to any ideas. However, would be far easier to customize Owl, than building a whole carousel with jquery from scratch with all the existing functionality plus the caption functionality mentioned above. But if you have a jquery plugin that does that please feel free to share as an answer and can take a look. If if you know the official term for a carousel like the one above and I can continue to research.

Comment: As i said in first comment, you can do it with `pure jquery` , i don't know any plugin similar what you want, but this looks so easy to write it, i'll make a example for you, stay tuned.